# Being Pythonic: Collecting arbitrary strings - indexer

Tags: python, python-2.x

Firstly, the code below works as is.  I'm much more of a Ruby programmer, so I'm still feeling my way along in Python and I feel confident that there must be a far more DRY way to accomplish what I'm doing below.

I'm building an indexer that creates a dictionary of terms that repeat in the document along with a count and then outputs the terms with the count.  Right now it supports up to four word phrases.  Is there a better way for me to abstract out this kind of logic so that I can do the same thing but for phrases of arbitrary lengths without needing to add more and more conditionals?

```
import sys
file=open(sys.argv[1],"r")
wordcount = {}
last_word = ""
last_last_word = ""
last_last_last_word = ""

for word in file.read().split():
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1

    if last_last_last_word != "":
        if "{} {} {} {}".format(last_last_last_word,last_last_word,last_word,word) not in wordcount:
            wordcount[last_last_last_word + " " + last_last_word + " " + last_word + " " + word ] = 1
        else: 
            wordcount[last_last_last_word + " " + last_last_word + " " + last_word + " " + word ] += 1
    last_last_last_word = last_last_word

    if last_last_word != "":
        if last_last_word + " " + last_word + " " + word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[last_last_word + " " + last_word + " " + word ] = 1
        else: 
            wordcount[last_last_word + " " + last_word + " " + word ] += 1
    last_last_word = last_word

    if last_word != "":
        if last_word + " " + word not in wordcount:
            wordcount[last_word + " " + word] = 1
        else: 
            wordcount[last_word + " " + word] += 1
    last_word = word

for k,v in sorted(wordcount.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
    print k,v
```

I'm including a more extensive sample input and output.  I apologize for the length but the nature of what this code does will tend to create large outputs.

This input:

```
this is a sample input file an input file will always be all lower case with no punctuation
```

Produces this output:

```
file 2
input 2
input file 2
an input file 1
all 1
lower case 1
be 1
is 1
file will always 1
an 1
sample 1
case 1
always be all lower 1
this is a 1
will always be 1
sample input file 1
will always 1
is a sample 1
all lower 1
lower case with no 1
no 1
with 1
with no 1
file will always be 1
with no punctuation 1
lower 1
be all lower case 1
no punctuation 1
an input file will 1
input file an 1
file an 1
input file an input 1
always be 1
file an input file 1
be all 1
is a 1
input file will 1
file will 1
an input 1
input file will always 1
will always be all 1
always be all 1
lower case with 1
a sample 1
a sample input file 1
a sample input 1
is a sample input 1
be all lower 1
a 1
sample input file an 1
sample input 1
case with no punctuation 1
all lower case with 1
this 1
always 1
file an input 1
case with 1
case with no 1
will 1
all lower case 1
punctuation 1
this is 1
this is a sample 1
```

Note that each word has been counted, each pair of words, each trio of words and each quartet of words.  I'd like to DRY out this code so that I can make this return counts up to an arbitrary set of words.

Comment: So what do you mean about `four word phrases`? Can you give us an example of the input and the expect output?

Comment: I think he meant four-word phrases.

Comment: @Pablo: So how to catch the four-word phrases?  - To OP: Do you mean just split the list `file.read().split()` in chunks?

Comment: Yes, @pablo. :)  I mean four word phrases... four words together that appear one or more times in that order in the file.  Ultimately I'd like to be able to create output for an arbitrary number of word phrases.

Comment: @KevinGuan I am already catching them with the code that I have, but it's not DRY.  That's my real problem.  If I can figure out how to make it DRY I can abstract this to support any number of terms.

Comment: If folks feel this is "too broad" please explain.  This question seems pretty specific to me.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, can you add a small example input and the expected output  explaining why?

Comment: Sure... Give me a few.  I have an example output already but I'll make something simple.

Comment: can you please show the input file...

Comment: @DavidHoelzer: Thanks for your edit. And the output which you want to get is?

Comment: will the word-sequence cross the boundary of a new line or not?

Comment: @KevinGuan Just as I have it now...  A list of all words, pairs of words, trios of words, quartets of words, quintets of words, etc. with their counts.  I'll likely add logic to drop out single occurrences since they will likely not be relevant (and the output will be massive!)

Comment: @pynchia Absolutely but they don't need to.  I'm stripping all formatting, etc. before processing with this script.

Comment: You are able to get the correct result ? Or you just want to make the code simpler ?

Comment: Ah, I understand. Your code is working, but you want a simple way to...for example if you need get quintets of words, and you don't want repeat the `if-if-else` again. Right?

Comment: @Rockybilly as I state in the introduction to the question, the posted code works correctly.  I'm trying to simplify and DRY the code to better support larger numbers of words in phrases more easily.

Comment: @KevinGuan  Yes, precisely.  You've got it now.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, do lines overlap or is each line considered separate in the file?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham What do you mean "overlap?"  I'm not sure I can imagine how a line in a text file can overlap another line.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, I mean the end of one line is not the end of the sentence that it carries over to the start of the next, there is a very big difference between the two

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes, that is certainly possible.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, then that is going to be your biggest problem, without knowing where the line in the context of the grammar  starts or  ends you have to consider that every line can overlap and every n length list of words are a phrase so I think not reading all the data into memory is going to be very hard.  You will find for any reasonable size file brute forcing is going to take an age

Comment: Well, that's why I'm tracking the last four words in my code rather than reading the entire file in.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, you might want to add that to your question, as it stands every answer is just splitting the data and treating it as one long list of words.  To do it efficiently there are no one or two line solutions.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, your code also  does read the whole file at once

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Good point.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer,  unless you define some rules where either each line is it's own entity or try to use punctuation if it exists in the original text which itself won't be trivial then you  have to consider the whole text as being one line   bar maybe using offsets and  reading the file numerous times starting at different positions.

Comment: Treating the entire file as a single line is just fine for my application.  As I stated, all punctuation is stripped ahead of time.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer, then you are always going to be storing two full copies of the data in memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go man. I think what you've been looking for was this.

```
string="this is a sample input file an input file will always be all lower case with no punctuation"

def words(count):
    return [" ".join(string.split()[a:b]) for a in range(len(string.split())) for b in range(a+count+1) if len(string.split()[a:b]) == count]
```

It's based on slicing the input text and returning the list of appropriate lenght of phrases.

Call the list with the lenght of the sequence you've been looking for.

```
lst = words(3)
```

And when you look up the result with a loop;

```
for word in set(lst):
    print word, lst.count(word)

an input file 1
file will always 1
is a sample 1
be all lower 1
file an input 1
with no punctuation 1
input file will 1
lower case with 1
this is a 1
always be all 1
will always be 1
sample input file 1
a sample input 1
all lower case 1
case with no 1
input file an 1
```

Yes, as the comments put, this is an inefficent method so I must apologize for that.

You stated you wanted the phrases extracted by arbitrary lenght, so if my first assumption was incorrect, here is another solution gives you the count of combinations of phrases without using .count() method.

**But** by using this, the whole text also counted as phrase as a whole so make sure you really certain about the lenght of these phrases you want.

```
words_list = string.split()
words_dict = {}

for a in range(len(words_list)):
    for b in range(a):
        phrase = " ".join(words_list[b:a])
        if phrase in words_dict:
            words_dict[phrase] += 1
        else:
            words_dict[phrase] = 1

for i in words_dict:
    print i, words_dict[i]
```

Gives you all lengths.

Comment: This doesn't match up with the provided output.

Comment: This also is highly inefficient, calling list.count is a very bad way to get the counts.

Comment: Let me try something else than, just a moment.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham So is this method better that .count() ?

Comment: Regarding your second method. Do you understand that you split the same string over and over a hell lot of times? Besides, your `if phrase in ... else` statement is a wheel reinvented - dicts have `setdefault` for that very sake.

Comment: @Rockybilly, `in words_dict.keys()` is an `0(n)` operation in python2 and an unnecessary method call using python3, you can just use `in words_dict` or better again just use a Counter dict and only split the string once

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for the advice, corrected it.

Comment: You shouldn't use `range` for indexing in Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

If your're concerned about a large file (perhaps one that doesn't even have line endings to allow line-by-line iteration), then you can memory map it (keeping memory usage low) and use a regex to isolate all lowercase words, create a sliding window of N words, then update a `Counter` appropriately, eg:

```
import re
import mmap
from itertools import islice, izip, tee
from collections import Counter
from pprint import pprint

def word_grouper(filename, size):
    counts = Counter()
    with open(filename) as fin:
        mm = mmap.mmap(fin.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_READ)
        words = (m.group() for m in re.finditer('[a-z]+', mm))
        sliding = [islice(w, n, None) for n, w in enumerate(tee(words, size+1))]
        for slide in izip(*sliding):
            counts.update(slide[:n] for n in range(1, len(slide)))

    return counts

counts = word_grouper('input filename', 4)
# do appropriate formatting instead of just `pprint`ing
pprint(counts.most_common())
```

Example output (where input file contains your example string):

```
[(('file',), 2),
 (('input', 'file'), 2),
 (('input',), 2),
 (('a', 'sample', 'input'), 1),
 (('file', 'will', 'always', 'be'), 1),
 (('sample', 'input', 'file', 'an'), 1),
 (('this', 'is', 'a', 'sample'), 1),
 (('this', 'is'), 1),
 (('will',), 1),
 (('lower', 'case', 'with'), 1),
 (('an', 'input', 'file', 'will'), 1),
 (('sample', 'input'), 1),
 (('is', 'a'), 1),
 (('all', 'lower', 'case', 'with'), 1),
 (('input', 'file', 'will'), 1),
 (('an',), 1),
 (('always', 'be'), 1),
 (('lower', 'case', 'with', 'no'), 1),
 (('an', 'input'), 1),
 (('be', 'all', 'lower'), 1),
 (('this',), 1),
 (('be', 'all', 'lower', 'case'), 1),
 (('this', 'is', 'a'), 1),
 (('sample',), 1),
 (('sample', 'input', 'file'), 1),
 (('will', 'always', 'be', 'all'), 1),
 (('a',), 1),
 (('a', 'sample'), 1),
 (('is', 'a', 'sample'), 1),
 (('will', 'always'), 1),
 (('lower',), 1),
 (('lower', 'case'), 1),
 (('file', 'an'), 1),
 (('file', 'an', 'input'), 1),
 (('file', 'will'), 1),
 (('is',), 1),
 (('all', 'lower'), 1),
 (('input', 'file', 'an', 'input'), 1),
 (('always', 'be', 'all', 'lower'), 1),
 (('an', 'input', 'file'), 1),
 (('input', 'file', 'an'), 1),
 (('be', 'all'), 1),
 (('input', 'file', 'will', 'always'), 1),
 (('be',), 1),
 (('all',), 1),
 (('always', 'be', 'all'), 1),
 (('is', 'a', 'sample', 'input'), 1),
 (('always',), 1),
 (('all', 'lower', 'case'), 1),
 (('file', 'an', 'input', 'file'), 1),
 (('file', 'will', 'always'), 1),
 (('a', 'sample', 'input', 'file'), 1),
 (('will', 'always', 'be'), 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick refactoring of your code, [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is your friend.

This takes the number of words you want to use it for as the second argument.

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

file=open(sys.argv[1],"r")

wordcount = defaultdict(int)
wordlist = ["" for i in range(int(sys.argv[2]))]

def check(wordcount, wordlist, word):

    wordlist.append(word)
    for i, word in enumerate(wordlist):
        if word != "":
            current = "".join([w + " " for w in wordlist[i:]])
            wordcount[current] += 1

    return wordlist[1:]

for word in file.read().split():
    wordlist = check(wordcount, wordlist, word)

for k,v in sorted(wordcount.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
    print k,v
```

Comment: This still doesn't make it DRY.

Comment: Also, I think you've actually broken the logic in the four word phrases.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer have a look now?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer this also matches up with the solution code you provided.

Comment: This looks good so far.  Thanks.. I'll evaluate the code and see if we get anything better than this.  My up vote can at least get you back to "Zero." :)

Comment: You shouldn't open files that way in Python. OP asked for Pythonic code.

Answer (score 0):

**Update** made it lazier

```
from collections import Counter
import itertools
import operator as op


def count_phrases(words, phrase_len):
    return reduce(op.add, 
    (Counter(tuple(words[i:i+l]) for i in xrange(len(words)-l+1)) for l in phrase_len))
```

Example:

```
words = "a b c a a".split()
for phrase, count in count_phrases(words, [1, 2]).iteritems():
    print " ".join(phrase), counts
```

Output:

```
b c 1
a 3
c 1
b 1
c a 1
a a 1
a b 1
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the logic is broken. The spaces are required, which are no longer maintained in your solution.

Comment: @UtsavShah How come the spaces are required?

Comment: His original code has spaces in them for keys, so they are like "word1 word2 word3", that's why. My guess is this is a natural language processing task.

Comment: @UtsavShah then only the word order matters, hence spaces are not important.

Comment: @EliKorvigo The spaces very much matter in the output.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer they will be there in the output

Comment: @DavidHoelzer as you see the last line (i.e. `print(" ".join(phrase), counts)`) returns the spaces

Comment: @DavidHoelzer and BTW, using tuples to store split words reduces memory consumption, because that way Python can reuse referenced objects instead of creating new copies in memory, hence returning spaces at the final step is superior performance-wise

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
def parser(data,size):
    chunked = data.split()
    phrases = []
    for i in xrange(len(chunked)-size):
        phrase=' '.join(chunked[i:size+i])
        phrases.append(phrase)
    return phrases

def parse_file(fname,size):    
    result = []
    with open(fname,'r') as f:    
        for data in f.readlines():
            for i in xrange(1,size):
                result+=parser(data.strip(),i)

    return Counter(result)


result= parse_file('file.txt',4) 
print sorted(result.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)

[('file', 2),
 ('input', 2),
 ('input file', 2),
 ('an input file', 1),
 ('all', 1),
 ('always be all', 1),
 ('is', 1),
 ('an', 1),
 ('sample', 1),
 ('this is a', 1),
 ('will always be', 1),
 ('sample input file', 1),
 ('will always', 1),
 ('is a sample', 1),
 ('all lower', 1),
 ('no', 1),
 ('with no', 1),
 ('lower case', 1),
 ('case', 1),
 ('input file will', 1),
 ('case with no', 1),
 ('input file an', 1),
 ('file an', 1),
 ('be', 1),
 ('always be', 1),
 ('be all lower', 1),
 ('be all', 1),
 ('lower', 1),
 ('is a', 1),
 ('an input', 1),
 ('a sample input', 1),
 ('lower case with', 1),
 ('a sample', 1),
 ('file will', 1),
 ('with', 1),
 ('a', 1),
 ('file will always', 1),
 ('sample input', 1),
 ('this', 1),
 ('always', 1),
 ('file an input', 1),
 ('case with', 1),
 ('will', 1),
 ('all lower case', 1),
 ('this is', 1)]
```

Comment: You've opened a file without the context managed and forgot to close it.

Comment: The files this is being run on will be massive.  Reading the entire file into memory first looks non-optimal.

Comment: You can use yield as well. I can update the code if this is the only problem

Comment: @AliNikneshan did you mean `f.readlines()` - as your current loop will loop over each character in the first line at present

Answer (score 0):

Humble contribution

```
import sys
file=open(sys.argv[1],"r")
wordcount = {}
nb_words = 4
last_words = []

for word in file.read().split():
    last_words = [word] + last_words 
    if len (last_words) > nb_words:
        last_words.pop()
    for i in range(len(last_words)-1,-1,-1):
        if last_words[i] != "":
            key = ' '.join(last_words[:i+1])
            if key not in wordcount:
                wordcount[key] = 1
            else: 
                wordcount[key] += 1

for k,v in sorted(wordcount.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True):
    print k,v
```

I programmed a loop to replace the variables. So now you have a parameter to go over 4 words.
Edit : after some bugfix, i am now sure it is producing the same output